# Как убрать транслит при определении русского текста?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Всех приветствую, прошу помощи. Пишу чтение текста с фото при помощи pytesseract.
Почему то русский текст выводит транслитом, не могу понять как настроить вывод на русском

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Tesseract\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('p.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config)

with open('text.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Comment: [Languages and scripts](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc#languages-and-scripts).

Comment: А как построить синтаксис ?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Вы попробовали указать язык для распознавания? Стало лучше? Что-то не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, получилось

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

import glob #Выбор файлов по маске

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Tesseract\\tesseract.exe'

listPic = glob.glob('**.jpg')
listPic.sort()

text = ''

for name in listPic:
    img = cv2.imread(name)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 '

    text = text + name + ' \n' + pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='rus+eng', config=config) + ' \n'

with open('text.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(text)
print('ready')
```